How to handle "hangup" event while processing a widget
I faced the Error - 81002 in Twillio call.
When a hangup event occurs during execution of a widget function, it interrupts without transitioning to the next flow.
Is there a way to capture the hangup event within the function?
Alternatively, please suggest other solutions to handle this.

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

Twilio Evangelist here,
When the caller hangup the call, the call status transitions to "completed". As it seems you're using a Studio Flow, you can implement a "Split Based On..." widget with the following variable to test (Outbound call: {{widgets.(WidgetName).DialCallStatus}}) or (Inbound Call:{{trigger.call.CallStatus}}), then include in the transition the desired call status to validate, in this case "completed". You can find the complete list here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#call-status-values
The following sample widget evaluates the "calling" widget call status, and a transition to another widget if it's equal to "busy":
StudioWidgetExample

Let me add a little more information.
As a result of our phone call, when 1# is pressed in widget, it transitions to the next function.
However, if the user hangs up right after pressing 1#, the function indicated here fails, and the above error is displayed.
Is there a way to handle this situation?

Could you please create a Support ticket and include the Studio Execution SID (FNxxxxxxx) where this behavior is present? This way we can identify the event triggered and how is the execution ending and give you a more accurate response.
